# Ubuntu Upgrade from version 18.10 to 19.04 FAILURE

Tags: upgrade

I get this error message:

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

any new ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at the log files mentioned in the error text? Did you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before dist-upgrade?

Comment: I would suggest that you back your important data and do a fresh install of 19.04.

Comment: no way to do again a fresh install... in this case, i would install another distro, but cannot assume which one is better than ubuntu

Comment: maybe Fedora or Manjaro. if the fixed release thing is really your issue. Fedora and Manjaro both have rolling release. which means there is no version number basically. when you run updates, you'll necessarily be at the latest version of everything. But be warned neither of the two use apt, they use yum and pacman/yahourt respectively. you'll have to learn a new package system and terminal commands. Just currious, why don't you want to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: do they have support forums like ubuntu has ? they are nice organised but cant say i received any extreme help here

Comment: The "ubresolvable problem" could have several possible causes. By far the most common occurs when the user adds non-Ubuntu sources or PPAs that introduce wrong-version or poorly-made packages. Return your Ubuntu system to as close to stock condition as possible: Uninstall ALL packages from those non-Ubuntu sources, disable those sources, verify that an apt-update and apt-upgrade have NO errors, then the release-upgrade will work.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.